# Register CPT if Jetpack Portfolio is not active and only once

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-jetpack

I am creating a theme and I want to include support for projects CPT in it. How can I activate my CPT only if Jetpack Portfolio is not active?

In addition, I am registering some custom fields with my projects, if the user decides to activate the Jetpack Portfolio, how can I still use my CPT and not interfere with Jetpack CPT?

Comment: This is very wrong idea. CPTs are content and should definitely not rely on **other** plugin being active. If your plugin can not work with jetpack, so be it, it is never smart to rely on 3rd party to not do something that will break your code

Comment: So you recommend me to create a new CPT, even if the user have jetpack projects activated.

Comment: This is a very high level question which is hard to answer in something that is not broad way, but iit is like asking should you use the same function name like a jetpack function. Maybe if you know very well what you are doing, but 99% of the time you should do things under your own "namespace"